# Implementing LINQ to Entity on many to one and one to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm tring to implement LINQ to Entity using Include extension.

I have the following scheme:

[image]

Here is my first LINQ (it works properly):

```
   var query = ctx1.Order_Details.Include("Order").Select( o => new  
             { o.OrderID,
               o.ProductID,
               o.Order.OrderDate,
               o.Order.OrderNumber
              });
```

Here is my second LINQ(doesn't work):

[image: Error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type]

My question is why when I'm implementing Linq on "many to one"  relationship LINQ works properly and when I'm trying to implement LINQ "inside out" (i.e. one to many) it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query works because there is just one related order for each order detail - you are looking at the relationship from the "n" perspective (the order details).

In the second query you are starting with the "1" in the 1:n relationship between Order and Order_Detail and you are trying to get **one** unit price - but there is a **collection** (the "n") of related united prices and quantities. Your current approach would only work if there is just one related `Order_Detail` for each `Order`.

If you wanted to grab the related unit price and quantities collections in your anonymous type you could do something like this:

```
 var query2 = ctx1.Order.Include("Order_Details").Select( o => new  
             { o.OrderID,
               o.CustomerID,
               UnitPrices = o.Order_Details.Select( od => od.UnitPrice),
               Quantities = o.Order_Details.Select( od => od.Quantity)
              });
```

Comment: BrokenGlass,thank you for the answer it is realy halped me,but steel im missing something.At my second LINQ u wrote that result get one UnitPrice and one Quntity.But why??? i didnt used in my LINQ filters or extension method like .first() or .last().Im a little bit confused maybe because i dont understand properly how LINQ works.Thenk you!

Comment: I said *you are trying to* get one UnitPrice - that's why it doesn't work - you are treating Order_Details as if it was a single object, but it is a collection

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but how about:

```
ctx1.Orders.... //not ctx1.Order
```

Comment: spender,after pluralized i get 2 another mistakes.